# finding subsets from 1-N

Tags: c++, debugging

I have written this program for finding the different possible subset from 1-N. The code works fine up to N=5, but after that it gives wrong output. What is the bug?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n, i,j ;
    cin>>n;
    int limit = 1<<n;
    int arr[limit];
    for( i=0; i<limit; i++)
        arr[i] = i+1;
    for( i=0; i<limit; i++){
        for( j=0; j<limit; j++){
            ( i & 1<<j)? printf("%d\t", arr[j]) : 0;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<(1<<n)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought C++ didn't support VLAs?

Comment: What did you discover when you tried to debug the program?

Answer (score 0):

```
int limit = 1<<n;
```

So if `n > 5`, you have `limit > 32`.

```
int arr[limit];
```

I'm assuming your implementation has VLAs as an extension, this is not in the language per the standard.

```
for( i=0; i<limit; i++)
    arr[i] = i+1;
for( i=0; i<limit; i++){
    for( j=0; j<limit; j++){
        ( i & 1<<j)
```

When `j >= 32`, you shift farther than the width of `int` (very probably, your `int`s are 32 bits wide, supported by the observation that your code doesn't work for `n > 5`), so that's undefined behaviour, and **very** unlikely to behave in a way to generate the correct output.

```
             ? printf("%d\t", arr[j]) : 0;
    }
```